# how to confirm java BufferedWriter successfully wrote to a text file

Tags: java, java-io, bufferedwriter

Making random password generator. Once password is generated, which I have no problem doing, the password is saved to a text file. I placed my `BufferedWriter` in a *try-with-resources* block, and have a catch block following, so i am notified if there is an `IOException`. But I want to somehow print(to the console) whether or not the password was actually written into the text file containing every password that i have randomly generated using this program.

```
// password generator above
// Export passwords to txt file to save:

        File destination = new File("/Users/danielpersonius/Desktop/random passwords.txt");
        if(!destination.exists()){
            destination.createNewFile();
        }
            try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(destination.getAbsoluteFile(),true))){
                // FileWriter(path, true) assures that the BufferedWriter appends to the previously created 
                // text file, not overwrites
                String formatted_output = String.format("%s%n", password);
                bw.write(formatted_output);
                Thread.sleep(1000); System.out.println("Password Successfully saved to \"random passwords.txt\"");
            }catch(IOException e){
               System.err.println("Export error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
```

Right now, the program automatically prints `Successfully saved...`, but is  there some way to actually test if it was, and print `Unsuccessful` if it was not written to the text file?

EDIT: Would a failure to write just show up in my catch block?

Comment: Do a flush and capture the IOException. If the flush succeeds the buffer is surely written to the underlying stream.

Comment: should i add the flush after 
bw.write(formatted_output) ?

Comment: yes. Just after the write.

Comment: BTW There is no advantage to using a buffered writer if you always write all the data you need in one go.  Without a buffer, the data will be flushed immediately.

Comment: Just move the "Password Successfully saved to..." output outside of the try-with-resources statement. If your program reached that point without an exception, then everything was fine. You also don't need that `Thread.sleep`.

Answer (score 2):

`write()` methods on `Writer`s in Java don't report the success of write, but they do throw `IOException` on failure.

If you have `BufferedWriter`, the write is cached before the actual write will happen and so in order to see the changes, you need to flush the content into `Writer` either by:

1. manually calling `flush()` method,
2. calling `close()` method that would automatically flush as well